# how can I combine a cell array and two scalars to obtain a cell array of string, scalar1, scalar2 elements in Octave avoiding loops?

Tags: combinations, octave, cell-array

I have a cell array like P and two other float variables

```
P = {"GG+G[G]", "GG", "GG-GGG", "GG[][GG]", "[G[GG-G]]", "G[GG]+[G]"};
val1 = 0.01;
val2 = 0.3;
```

And I would like to build the following data structure without using a loop because the P cell array can contain a large number of elements:

```
Inputparam = 
{
    [1,1] = {
              [1,1] = "GG+G[G]"
              [1,2] = 0.01
              [1,3] = 0.3
            }
    [1,2] = {
              [1,1] = "GG"
              [1,2] = 0.01
              [1,3] = 0.3
            }
    [1,3] = {
              [1,1] = "GG-GGG"
              [1,2] = 0.01
              [1,3] = 0.3
            }
    [1,4] = {
              [1,1] = "GG[][GG]"
              [1,2] = 0.01
              [1,3] = 0.3
            }
    [1,5] = {
              [1,1] = "[G[GG-G]]"
              [1,2] = 0.01
              [1,3] = 0.3
            }
    [1,6] = {
              [1,1] = "G[GG]+[G]"
              [1,2] = 0.01
              [1,3] = 0.3
            }
}
```

I've tried several options but with most of them what I got was a concatenation and not a combination of the elements.

The purpose of this structure is to be the argument of `parcellfun` function that's why I need to have each element of P, with `val1` and `val2` values.

I'm also considering using an anonymum function instead of allocation all this data in memory. does it make sense?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that, instead of a cell array of cells arrays, you create a 2D cell array, just because this is much easier to generate and, for large arrays, it takes up less memory too:

```matlab
P = {"GG+G[G]", "GG", "GG-GGG", "GG[][GG]", "[G[GG-G]]", "G[GG]+[G]"};
P(2,:) = 0.01;
P(3,:) = 0.2;
```

The cell array is indexed using `P{1,5}`, rather than `P{5}{1}` as the cell array in the OP.

Another alternative is to use struct arrays:

```matlab
P = {"GG+G[G]", "GG", "GG-GGG", "GG[][GG]", "[G[GG-G]]", "G[GG]+[G]"};
P = struct('name',P,'val1',0.01,'val2',0.2);
```

The struct is indexed as `P(5).name` rather than `P{5}{1}` (and `P(5).val1` instead of `P{5}{2}`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Cris but, and sorry because I realise that I didn't mention it in my question, I would need to have the string, the param1 and the param2 in the same "block" of data. I want to parallelise a function and `inputparam` structure would be the argument to `parcellfun` function.

Comment: I just looked at the documentation to `parcellfun`, it's not very detailed... You could try `pararrayfun` using the struct as input. Creating your cell array of cell arrays would need a loop, I think. It'll also have a larger memory overhead. @MariaJCasas

Comment: Uhmmm, interesting suggestion. I hadn't realized of it. I'll try it using `pararrayfun`. Thanks!! @cris-luengo